# How do I access records in node.js using 'has-many belongs-to relationaship'?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am new to node.js. I am using sequelize in my app. 
I have the following models:

```
var Topic = sequelize.define('Topic', {
  topic_name: Sequelize.STRING,
  topic_category: Sequelize.STRING
},{tableName: 'Topics'})

var RawStatistic = sequelize.define('RawStatistic', {
  feedback_value: Sequelize.STRING,
  count: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  total_feedbacks_for_this_topic: Sequelize.INTEGER
},{tableName: 'RawStatistics'})
```

And the rellation between them as follows:

```
RawStatistic.belongsTo(Topic);
Topic.hasMany(RawStatistic);
```

But when I use:

```
    RawStatistic.all({limit: FIVE}).success(function (raw_statistics) {
    raw_statistics.getTopic().success(function (r){
    res.json(r)
    });
  });
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getTopic'
```

My question is how do I access a particular Topic name if I have a Feedback record?
What is the syntax for the same? Probably I am overlooking an obvious syntax to achieve this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: How did you define your `Topics`? Singular? Or plural? Note that _all_ models in sequelize should be defined in singular. Also, a `RawStatstics` belongs to _one_ topic, therefore you cannot use `getTopics()`, but `getTopic()` (there's only one).

Comment: @Zeta you are right, I had defined 'Topics' instead of 'Topic'.Thanks. I have made corrections and updated the question but I am still getting the same error. Don't know what I missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use an instance method on a collection of instances. You need to iterate over the result:

```
RawStatistic.all({limit: FIVE}).success(function (raw_statistics) {
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < raw_statistics.length; ++i){
    raw_statistics[i].getTopic().success(function (t){
      /* ... */
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Omg I overlooked something that was really basic. Thanks alot for your help :)